# Simplify Update method switch statment

Tags: c#

In my `Update` method i have switch statment which is exactly the same in two places over that method. is there anyway to simplify that code?

```cs
public void Update(DomainLayer.Models.Client.Client client)
{
    if (client.ClientId != null)
    {
        if (_clientQuery.IsNameExistWithinClient(client.SectorId, (int)client.ClientId, client.Name))
        {
            switch (client)
            {
                case BottleClient bottleClient:
                    _bootleclientRepository.Update(bottleClient);
                    break;
                case HatClient hatClient:
                    _hatclientRepository.Update(hatClient);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (_clientQuery.IsNameExistWithinSector(client.SectorId, client.Name))
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(msgType: MsgType.Error,
                    "Such client name already exist for that sector", "Applciation exception");
            }

            switch (client)
            {
                case BottleClient bottleClient:
                    _bootleclientRepository.Update(bottleClient);
                    break;
                case HatClient hatClient:
                    _hatclientRepository.Update(hatClient);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
        throw new ApplicationException(msgType: MsgType.Error,
            "ClientID is null", "Applciation exception");
}
```

**Edit**: After extraction i have this:

```
 public void Update(DomainLayer.Models.Client.Client client)
        {
            if (client.ClientId == null)
                throw new ApplicationException(msgType: MsgType.Error,
                    "ClientID is null", "Applciation exception");

            if (_clientQuery.IsNameExistWithinClient(client.SectorId, (int)client.ClientId, client.Name))
                UpdateIt(client);
            else
            {
                if (_clientQuery.IsNameExistWithinSector(client.SectorId, client.Name))
                    throw new ApplicationException(msgType: MsgType.Error,
                        "Such client name already exist for that sector", "Applciation exception");

                UpdateIt(client);
            }

        }

        private void UpdateIt(DomainLayer.Models.Client.Client client)
        {
            switch (client)
            {
                case BottleClient bottleClient:
                    _bottleClientRepository.Update(bottleClient);
                    break;
                case HatClient hatClient:
                    _hatClientRepository.Update(hatClient);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: There's a refactoring: Extract method

Comment: @ThomasWeller i extracted but still in code there is call to that function, is there anyway to simplify more besides extracting switch?

Comment: @ThomasWeller i provided modified code - any chance to simplify more? See my main post again.

Comment: You may check about Strategy Pattern. It reduce switch case on `Type`. However it takes effort to implement. Effort worth it if you would have tons of client type in the future.

Comment: @LouisGo i know what you mean but if you look closer method belongs to repository its not in client directly.

Comment: @Arie You need to pass a delegate or inject dependency to redirect the call to functions. It's still Strategy Pattern. However it may be not worth it, if it's not growing extensively in the future.

Comment: If you have it in all cases (`if` and `else`), you can write it after the `if` statement

Answer (score 1):

Just put the:

```
switch (client)
        {
            case BottleClient bottleClient:
                _bootleclientRepository.Update(bottleClient);
                break;
            case HatClient hatClient:
                _hatclientRepository.Update(hatClient);
                break;
        }
```

outside the if/else statement? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If and Else can be combined in one if condition with &&. See below code:

```
public void Update(DomainLayer.Models.Client.Client client)
{
    if (client.ClientId == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(msgType: MsgType.Error,
            "ClientID is null", "Applciation exception");
    }

    if (!_clientQuery.IsNameExistWithinClient(client.SectorId, (int)client.ClientId, client.Name) &&
        _clientQuery.IsNameExistWithinSector(client.SectorId, client.Name))
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(msgType: MsgType.Error,
                "Such client name already exist for that sector", "Applciation exception");

    }
    switch (client)
    {
        case BottleClient bottleClient:
            _bootleclientRepository.Update(bottleClient);
            break;
        case HatClient hatClient:
            _hatclientRepository.Update(hatClient);
            break;
    }           
}
```

Comment: You could also throw earlier `if (client.ClientId == null)`